# Transformar data objeto em datetime (ano mes dia) python

Tags: python, data

Preciso transformar uma data que está com formato `obj` em `datetime` para realizar um cálculo.

A coluna está nesse formato:

```
01JUN2020:00:00:01  
01OUT2020:00:00:02
01MAI2020:00:00:04
```

Tentei a função datetime, mas não consegui.

```
df['data_nova'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'],format='%d%b%Y').strptime
```

Mas retorna o erro `ValueError: unconverted data remains: :00:00:00`

Ao apenas transformar em datetime também não é possível

```
df['ArrivalDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'])
Unknown string format: 01MAI2020:00:00:00
```

O objetivo final é criar um novo campo com a subtração da data atual com o campo data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas coisas no exemplo que você postou:

1. Os meses estão abreviados em maiúsculo
2. Os meses estão em português

Para o primeiro caso, usar o `title` resolve.

Para o segundo caso tem que usar uma função para replace

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"data": ["01JUN2020:00:00:01", "01AUG2020:00:00:04"]})

>>> df
                 data
0  01JUN2020:00:00:01
1  01AUG2020:00:00:04

>>> df['nova_data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'].str.title(),format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')

>>> df
                 data           nova_data
0  01JUN2020:00:00:01 2020-06-01 00:00:01
1  01AUG2020:00:00:04 2020-08-01 00:00:04
```

dataframe info

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------     --------------  -----
 0   data       2 non-null      object
 1   nova_data  2 non-null      datetime64[ns]   <<<<<------
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(1)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
```

Para o segundo caso

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"data": ["01JUN2020:00:00:01", "01MAI2020:00:00:04"]})

>>> df['nova_data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'].str.replace('MAI', 'May'),format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

Este dataframe

```
>>> print(df)
                 data           nova_data
0  01JUN2020:00:00:01 2020-06-01 00:00:01
1  01MAI2020:00:00:04 2020-05-01 00:00:04
>>>
```

**Atualização baseado no comentário**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"data": ["01FEV2020:00:00:01", "01MAI2020:00:00:04"]})

>>> df
                 data
0  01FEV2020:00:00:01
1  01MAI2020:00:00:04

>>> df['nova_data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'].str.replace('MAI', 'May').str.replace('FEV', 'Feb'),format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')

>>> df
                 data           nova_data
0  01FEV2020:00:00:01 2020-02-01 00:00:01
1  01MAI2020:00:00:04 2020-05-01 00:00:04
```

Comment: É possível realizar o str replace para todos os meses (minha base possui todos em português)? tentei por dicionário, mas não estava funcionando

Comment: Post atualizado a partir de seu comentário. Coloquei apenas dois meses, mas pode fazer com os que precisarem.

Answer (score 2):

Vou fazer uma modificação na [resposta do Paulo Marques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/498019/137387) pois concordo que o fato dos meses estarem abreviados em maiúsculo é um problema para obter a solução.

Porém os sistemas operacionais fornecem um banco de dados de internacionalização onde você apenas instala no sistema operacional um pacote de especificações linguísticas e culturais. As linguagens de programação fornecem o acesso a esse banco de dados e com *Python* não é diferente.
O mecanismo de internacionalização permite que os programadores lidem com certas questões culturais em uma aplicação, sem exigir que o programador conheça todas as especificidades de cada país onde o software é executado.

Dentro da linguagem Python é disponibilizado o módulo [locale](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/locale.html) que abre o acesso ao banco de dados de localidades.

Inicialmente use [`setlocale()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) para modificar suas configurações de localização com os parâmetros:

- [`locale.LC_TIME`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/locale.html#locale.LC_TIME) : Especificador para localizações de tempo e data.
- [`locale.normalize('pt_BR.utf8')`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/locale.html#locale.normalize) : Retorna um código de localidade normalizado para localidade fornecida.

Assim permitindo que um usuário em qualquer parte do mundo possa utilizar o seu software com dados em linguagem nativa.

```
>>> import locale
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> try:
...    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, locale.normalize('pt_BR.utf8'))
... except locale.Error:
...    print('Instale o módulo de linguagem adequado no seu Sistema Operacional.')

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"data": ["01JUN2020:00:00:01", "01OUT2020:00:00:02", "01MAI2020:00:00:04"]})

>>> df['nova_data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'].str.title(),format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')

>>> df
```

Resultado no Windows:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Resultado no Linux:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]